# BizTalk 2010 Execute batch error. Exception information: TDDS failed to batch execution of streams. SQLServer

Tags: sql, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Getting this error in the event log every 5 mins**

> EventID: 5 
>   Log Name:Application  
>   Execute batch error. Exception information: 
>   TDDS failed to batch execution of streams. 
>   SQLServer: XXXXXSQL01\xxxxxxxSQL01,1111, Database: BAMPrimaryImport.Parameter is not valid

[image]

**BizTalk 2010**

looked at this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2013/11/26/bam-tracking-data-getting-accumulated-in-the-biztalkmsgbox-database/

https://mwoodsmcpd.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/bam-eventbus-service-errors-and-warnings/

Comment: Did you see this one as well? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52aac3d8-078b-4f48-835a-6492848e9a7b/tdds-failed-to-batch-execution-of-streamsparameter-is-not-valid?forum=biztalkesb